# Links to other pages in JSF

Tags: jsf, navigation

From Core Server Faces I read this:

*If no mapping from outcome to view ID is given*

> - If the outcome doesn't have a file extension, then append the    extension of the current view.
> - If the outcome doesn't start with a /, then prepend the path of the current view.

So does this mean that you can't use relative links in for example `<h:link outcome="../index.xhtml" ... />`? Do you always need to provide absolute links? At least it doesn't work when I try relative links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, you just need to have a .xtml file at the said locaiton:

```
admin/
  login.xhtml
home.xhtml
```

Comment: I was fooled by how it works when you use templates..I used it relative to section. Great, thanks.